# How is iodine-131 produced in nuclear reactors?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I coulnd't find clear explanations about the production of Iodine-131 in nuclear reactors based on U-235.

- Can it be derived directly from U-235 ? In this case : U-235 + neutron -> I-131 + what ???
- Or is it derived indirectly from U-235 ? In this case : U-235 + neutron -> X ? -> I-131 (what could be X? And by which process? neutron impact on X or beta-decay of X?)

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 4):

It is a fission product, one of many nuclides: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/fisfrag.html

As uranium has Z=92 and iodine Z=53, the other piece could be yttrium (Z=39). But total Z may change because of all the beta-decays. The iodine isotope is likely a decay product of short-lived fission products like In-131, Sn-131, Sb-131, Te-131.

Comment: Hi Pieter, in your link, there is a table "Table of fission fragments" in which I-131 is not listed as a possible direct fission product of U-235. So, I-131 does appear, of course, but the chain of reactions leading to it remains a mystery...

Comment: Uranium, like most heavy elements has a higher N/Z than lighter elements, at least their stable isotopes. Of course, neutron-induced fission of U-235 produces 2 extra neutrons, but you still have quite an excess. Z _will_ increase, in the decay chains, to bring N/Z down to stable levels via beta decay. I'd look at e.g. Sn-131 (N=50) and Mo-102 (N=42), both unstable under beta decay. (Note that N adds up to 92, Z to 233. U-235 of course has Z=235 but fission produces neurons). Sn-131 will decay to I-131.

Comment: The thesis you will find here : « https://esirc.emporia.edu/handle/123456789/3523 » looks quite interesting. Look at page 89 ; it gives a way for directly producing I-131 :
U-235 + 1n -> U-236 -> Y-101 + I-131 + 4n
Surely, many other ways are possible, through beta-decay of Te, Sn or else ; but at least, I have something to eat…

Answer (score 1):

Uranium only serves as a neutron source. Yes, the decay reaction produces I-131, but it's in the radioactive waste, and it would be a pain to extract it. Your typical reactor fuel is left in for many years, during which quite a bit of the produced I-131 would decay again. Plus, the waste is quite radioactive, making it inconvenient to handle. And you get a lot of I-129 that you can't chemically separate.

Actual production is based on a convenient fact: Natural Tellurium can be radiated with neutrons from U-235 fission. This will produce a wide variation of isotopes, but if you give the short-lived isotopes time to decay (~few hours), let the Xenon escape, and chemically remove the remaining Tellurium, you'll find that the remaining mixture is very rich in I-131.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the question, this was about producing isotopes for medical purposes etc.

Comment: Could you write a reaction (or a chain of reactions) starting with U-235 and leading to I-131? I'm sorry to say, but it seems that nobody knows...

Comment: @Andrew: The point of this answer is, that's not how you do it. Uranium is there to produce neutrons, the bulk of the Z for iodine-131 comes from Te-130. (Via Te-131)

Comment: OK. I found : Te-130 + neutron -> Te-131 -> I-131 by beta decay. Now, do we have U-235 -> ... -> Te-130 ?

Comment: @Andrew: No, read what I wrote before.

Comment: You wrote : "Natural Tellurium can be radiated with neutrons from U-235 fission." Does it mean that natural tellurium is already inside the nuclear fuel? So that : (a) U-235 fissioned -> neutrons (b) neutrons emitted hurt Te-130, which was already present inside nuclear fuel AND NOT produced by U-235 fission (c) Te-130 -> Te-131 (d) Te-131 -> I131. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, you put the natural Tellurium next to a working reactor (Pu or U, doesn't matter). You don't mix it with the U-235, because it's then a pain to get it out again.

Comment: I dont understand "next to a working reactor". Let me reformulate : everybody says that I131 is formed in nuclear reactors and is hazardous (so many exercises for students in physics are about Chernobyl or Fukushima and include calculations on Cesium 137 or Iodine 131), but noboby seems to know how I131 is formed in the reactors... It amazes me. And I do want to know. Clearer?

Comment: @Andrew: Right, that seems to be a major misunderstanding there. I-131 is _intentionally_ produced, e.g. for medical reasons, in the way that I describe (Tellurium on the side). But when you refer to Chernobyl & Fukushima, you're talking about the unintentional radioactive waste.  See Pieter's answer for that.

Answer (score -1):

Most radiopharmaceuticals are accelerator produced. Less costly than building a reactor. Accelerators offer a lower radiation risk to workers and essentially zero risk to the public.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question though. Can you please elaborate?